# Regex to find a string that star with '-' and end with ')' that not contain '('

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I working in convert a dictionary text file to JSON. And I want to delete some strings in the dictionary file by Sublime text 3 search.

Ex:

```
@addle-head /'ædlhed/ (addle-pate) /'ædlpeit/
-pate) 
/'ædlpeit/
*  danh từ
- người đầu óc lẫn quẫn
```

I want to find and delete string "-pate)".

I've tried this code after google not contain string regex and AND operator regex:

`/^-((?!\().)*$/gm`

But it just can find a string start with '-' and not contain '('.

I expect a regex that can find string that and with ')' too.

Update:
The answer of MonkeyZeus is perfect for me. But I onky need a string that starts with '-' so I need to add '^' to the begin of the Regex like vs97 said in the comment. Thank all of you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
^-[^()]+\)$
```

Edited per the comment.

https://regex101.com/r/oGZ20d/6

Comment: I believe he wants only that the string starts with a -, so you are missing a ^ at the beginning of your regex (currently matches -pate in (addle-pate)). Or a $ at the end.

Comment: @vs97 Thanks, I submitted this answer before OP's post was edited to reveal the multiple lines but I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also tackle this problem by using Negative Lookahead:

```
^-(?!\().+\)$
```

[image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hdZmiM/1). Top right corner you can find explanation for all parts of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :
`\-{1}[^()]*\)`

[image]